# Prove that the two sets are identical.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the function $g(n):N\rightarrow R^+$ and two sets defined as follows:

$o(g(n)) = ${$f(n):N\rightarrow R^+|\forall c \in R^+$ $\exists n_0\in N$ $\forall n\geq n_0: f(n)<c \centerdot g(n)$}

$m(g(n)) = ${$f(n):N\rightarrow R^+|\forall c \in R^+$ $\exists n_0\in N$ $\forall n\geq n_0: f(n)\leq c \centerdot g(n)$}

Prove that the two sets are identical.
Would you advise me how to solve it please?

Comment: You have to show that the two sets have the same elements. For instance, if $f\in o(g(n))$, why is $f\in m(g(n))$? If $f\in m(g(n))$, why is $f\in o(g(n))$?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an element in $m(g(n))$, then you *can't* just change the $\le$ to $<$. See if you can come up with a different $c$ such that the inequality holds strictly. (Note that $g(n)\ge0$ according to your definition of $g$.)